# Replication of data

Tags: r

It might be simple, but I am not finding the solution I have a tibble of values for one year and would generate the same set for the next 40 years. A small example would look like this (the real data is 2000 x 6)

```
data <- as_tibble(data.frame(yr =c(2010,2010,2010), values = c("a","b","c")))
```

Now, I would like have the same set of observations of "values" for the years 2011 until 2050.
Any idea how to do this in R?

Thanks
Renger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative too. Useful if you're modeling:

```
library(modelr)
library(dplyr)
data1 %>% 
  data_grid(yr=2010:2050,values=values)
```

Comment: Thanks for all those quick replies! I used the last suggestion but the others are alos fine.

Answer (score 5):

Check this solution:

```
tidyr::crossing(
  yr = 2010:2050,
  values = c("a","b","c")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R way using `lapply`

```
lapply(2011:2050, function(x) data.frame(yr = x, values = data$values))
```

This would give you a list of dataframes for each year.

Output for 3 values

```
lapply(2011:2013, function(x) data.frame(yr = x, values = data$values))


#[[1]]
#    yr values
#1 2011      a
#2 2011      b
#3 2011      c

#[[2]]
#    yr values
#1 2012      a
#2 2012      b
#3 2012      c

#[[3]]
#    yr values
#1 2013      a
#2 2013      b
#3 2013      c
```